# RxJS5 - combineLatest not accessing Angular's local properties

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I need to call two http services and one socket. The first http call is to get meta data and set locally one of its values. Then, I need to call the second http service that returns initial values which are updated via a socket afterwards.

This is what I have so far:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    subscription: Subscription;
    title: string;
    prop1: number;
    prop2: number;

    constructor(private http: HttpService,
                private socket: SocketService,
                private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

ngOnInit() {
    this.prop1 = this.route.snapshot.parent.params['prop1'];
    this.subscription = this.http.get('/metaData')
        .do(data => {
            this.title = data.title;
            this.prop2 = data.prop2;
        })
        //this.prop2 is undefined in combineLatest...
        .combineLatest(
            this.http.get('initialData', { prop1: this.prop1, prop2: this.prop2 }),
            this.socket.get('updateEvents', { prop1: this.prop1, prop2: this.prop2 }),
            this.updateList)
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.data = data
        })

}
```

I believe I am close, but it appears that the `combineLatest` operator is not accessing local vars as the `prop2` is `undefined`. Is this because I am doing a `side effect` in the `do` operator that prop2 is not seen by the `combineLatest` on time?

Note: If I were to use `switchMap`, prop2 works, like this:

```
.switchMap(data => this.http.get('initialData', { prop1: this.prop1, prop2: this.prop2 }))
```

Why is prop2 `undefined` when using `combineLatest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the arguments passed to `combineLatest` are evaluated before `combineLatest` is called - and, therefore, before the `do` receives a next notification, etc.

You can use [`defer`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-defer) to solve the problem:

```ts
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/defer';

// ...

.combineLatest(
    Observable.defer(() => this.http.get('initialData', { prop1: this.prop1, prop2: this.prop2 })),
    Observable.defer(() => this.socket.get('updateEvents', { prop1: this.prop1, prop2: this.prop2 })),
    this.updateList
)

// ...
```